# IE equivalent of -moz/webkit-padding-end?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a select control with my own dropdown arrow (a background image positioned to the right).

Because my down arrow is 26px wide it obscures some of the text in the select. To counter this I'm using -padding-end

```
  -webkit-padding-end: 35px;
  -moz-padding-end: 35px;
```

I do not know what the equivalent is in IE. Does it have one or should I use another technique?

Answer (score 0):

#### The prefix used for IE properties in CSS is -ms-

In your specific case, you can't use `padding-end: 35px;` nor `-ms-padding-end: 35px;`
because there isn't such property used on IE.
You'll have to review your code in order to find how to solve that with existing properties for IE. Maybe the standard **`padding`** properties might help you:

```
padding-top
padding-bottom
```